# How can I assign a color range to edges in igraph plot in R based on edge attributes?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large social network plot that I am trying to color-code using the strength of the connections between individuals. In `mock_table`, the individuals are listed in column `a` and `b`, and the strength of each connection is given in column `c`.

I was successful in properly assigning these strength values to the `edge.width` function, however, when I  attempt to apply this to the `edge.color`, the values do not properly align. The colors in the plot do represent `sn_color`, but they are not assigned to the proper edges. The thickest edges (strongest connection, largest `c`-value) should also have the darkest color and vice versa.

Below is a simplified version of my current code:

```
mock_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(a=c("PO", "BL", "MA", "AL", "BL"), b=c("MA", "BO", "ED", "MA", "MA"), c=as.numeric(c(8,41,10,23,50))))
mock_table$c <- as.numeric(as.character(mock_table$c))

sn_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mock_table, vertices = c("PO", "BL", "MA", "AL", "BO", "ED"), directed = FALSE)
sn_proximity <- (mock_table$"c")

sn_colorrange <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "orange", "red", "darkred"))
sn_color <- sn_colorrange(length(sn_proximity))

plot(sn_graph,
     edge.width=(1/3)*(sn_proximity),
     edge.color=sn_color
     )
```

Would anyone be able to help me figure out how I can properly assign this color palette? Thanks so much!

*Edited to include reproducible example code.*

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, I just updated the post with reproducible example code. If there is anything else I can add, please let me know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the plot exactly which color to use. If you wanted to use a different color for each from the ramp, then you could do something like

```
plot(sn_graph,
     edge.width=(1/3)*(sn_proximity),
     edge.color=sn_color[order(sn_proximity)]
)
```

Otherwise it may be more common to set a fixed number of bins and then use `cut()` to the color has more meaning

```
n_bins <- 5
sn_color <- sn_colorrange(n_bins)
plot(sn_graph,
     edge.width=(1/3)*(sn_proximity),
     edge.color=sn_color[cut(sn_proximity, breaks=n_bins )]
)
```

Comment: The second bin option ended up working. Thank you!