# igraph: How to assign a gradient of colors to edges and vertices?

Tags: r, colors, gradient, igraph

I am trying to assign the same color gradient to both, edges and vertices on `igraph` using `R`. The gradient should color from low to high counts in the V(data_graph)$Counts portion.

Some reproducible data:

```
library(igraph) 
data <- data.frame(Country = c("Africa", "Argentina", "Bolivia", "Chile", "France", "Guam", "Poland", "Greenland", "Switzerland", "UK", "US"), 
               Counts = c(2,2,8,1,5,3,3,15, 15,30,35), 
               Pillar = c(rep("SoS", 4), rep("CNES", 4), rep("STE", 3)))

data_center <- setNames(data.frame("c", 1, "Sos"), names(data))
data_vtx <- rbind(data_center, data)
data_rel <- data.frame(from = head(data_vtx$Country, 1), 
                    to = data_vtx$Country[2:12])
```

which produces the following graph:

```
data_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(data_rel,  directed = FALSE, data_vtx)

plot(data_graph, 
 layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(data_graph),
 vertex.size = round(V(data_graph)$Counts/1.5, 2), 
 vertex.label.color = "black",
 edge.curved = 0.3)
```

However, next I would like to apply the same color gradient to both, the vertex and the edges based on the `V(data_graph)$Counts`. What I need is something similar to the `scale_color_gradient2` command from `ggplot2`.

Example:

```
scale_color_gradient2(low = “blue”, mid = “yellow”, high = “red”, midpoint = mean(V(data_graph)$Counts))
```

The closest I have found is the following post: [How can I assign color range to edges in igraph plot in R based on edge attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974308/how-can-i-assign-a-color-range-to-edges-in-igraph-plot-in-r-based-on-edge-attrib) This post was very informative on making a color gradient in `igraph`, but each edge there has it's own color. Because some of the V(data_graph)$Counts are the same, they should be colored the same in the color gradient.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are plotting `data_graph` but your example code does not produce that object - nor any graph.   Please add the missing code.

Comment: Thank you G5W for pointing that out. I have edited to include the line of code that was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colorRampPalette` to create the color ramp from blue to yellow to red.  Then use the Counts to select the colors for both the vertices and the edges. I used a somewhat arbitrary way of selecting the colors, but you can adjust the aesthetics to your taste.

```
CRP = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))

plot(data_graph, 
 layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(data_graph),
 vertex.size = round(V(data_graph)$Counts/1.5, 2), 
 vertex.label.color = "black",
 vertex.color = CRP(19)[round(V(data_graph)$Counts/2)+1],
 edge.color   = CRP(19)[round(V(data_graph)$Counts/2)+1],
 edge.curved = 0.3)
```

[image: Graph with colored edges]

Comment: Thank-you for this. Yes, this does show a gradient, as expected. However, I am looking for a solution similar to `scale_color_gradient2` (above post) where I can use mean(V(data_graph)$Counts) as the midpoint of the gradient - so all circles below the mean show a gradient from blue to yellow and above the mean shows yellow to red. 
Lastly, because some of the V(data_graph)$Counts are the same, they should be colored the same in the color gradient. This method gives the colors for each circle a gradient from blue to yellow to red. It does not take the mean(V(data_graph)$Counts into account.

Comment: Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your palette is known. If not see [Gradient of n colors ranging from color 1 and color 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353213/gradient-of-n-colors-ranging-from-color-1-and-color-2).
Add the Palette to the `data` and `data_center` data frames.
Add vertex and edge colors to the `plot()` statement.

```
library(igraph)

data <- data.frame(Country = c("Africa", "Argentina", "Bolivia", "Chile", "France", "Guam", "Poland", "Greenland", "Switzerland", "UK", "US"), 
               Counts = c(2,2,8,1,5,3,3,15, 15,30,35), 
               Pillar = c(rep("SoS", 4), rep("CNES", 4), rep("STE", 3)),
              Palette = rainbow(11)  # <<< 
         )

data_center <- setNames(data.frame("c", 1, "Sos", "black"), names(data)) # <<< center color  is black
data_vtx <- rbind(data_center, data)
data_rel <- data.frame(from = head(data_vtx$Country, 1), 
                         to = data_vtx$Country[-1]
            )
                    
data_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(data_rel,  directed = FALSE, data_vtx)

set.seed(202212)
plot(data_graph, layout = layout_as_star(data_graph),
 vertex.size        = round(V(data_graph)$Counts/1.5, 2), 
 vertex.color       = data_vtx$Palette,
 vertex.label.color = "black",
 edge.width         = 3,
 edge.curved        = 0.3,
 edge.color         = data_vtx$Palette[-1]
)
```

To make the palette, and assuming G5W's suggestion.

```
CRP          <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
cols         <- CRP(max(data$Counts) + 1)
data$Palette <- cols[data$Counts + 1] # instead of rainbow(11)

## Or use rank instead of population.
data$Palette <- CRP(nrow(data))[rank(data$Counts, ties.method="first")]
```

Comment: Thank-you for this. No, unfortunately I don't know my gradient. However, what I'm looking for is a way to do a gradient similar to `ggplot2` `scale_color_gradient2` command where I can choose a low, midpoint, high gradient (above post). I would then use mean(V(data_graph)$Counts) as the midpoint of the gradient - so all circles below the mean show a gradient from blue to yellow and above the mean shows yellow to red.

Comment: If you move this additional information to the question, you are more likely to get more useful answers.

Having found the answer, you can move the results to the data frames  as described.

Comment: clp - I have always had that information on the question. Please see above question.

Comment: I found your comment about the color yellow as the center point very helpful. I have expanded my answer to include making the gradient.